# How to find out the name of the theme that I'm using in wordpress from the database?

Tags: wordpress, malware

One of my site was infected with malware and has more than 20 templates installed and I can not remember the name of the template being used, I wonder if there is a way I can find the name of the theme is sindo used by bank data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform following db query on wp_option table.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name = 'template'
OR option_name = 'stylesheet'
OR option_name = 'current_theme';
```